# PHP Language Editor, Array Keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have found the script.
http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=24155

My lang.php

```
<?php
$Lang = array(
'TEXT'      => "baer",
'GRET'      => "hallo",
'FACE'      => "face",
'HAPY'      => "happy",
'TOOL'      => "tool",
);
```

My edit.php

```
<?
// edit the values of an array ($Lang["key"] = "value";) in the file below
$array_file = "lang.php";

// if POSTed, save file
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    unset($_POST['submit']);  // remove the submit button from the name/value pairs
    $new_array = "";          // initialize the new array string (file contents)
    $is_post = true;          // set flag for use below

    // add each form key/value pair to the file
    foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
        { $new_array .= "\$Lang[\'$key\'] => \"".trim($_POST[$key])."\",\n"; }

    // write over the original file, and write a backup copy with the date/time
    write_file($array_file, $new_array);
    write_file($array_file . date("_Y-m-d_h-ia"), $new_array);
    }

// write a file
function write_file($filename, $contents)
    {
    if (! ($file = fopen($filename, 'w'))) { die("could not open $filename for writing"); }
    if (! (fwrite($file, $contents))) { die("could not write to $filename"); }
    fclose($file);
    }

// read the array into $Lang[]
$file_lines = file($array_file);
$Lang = array();
foreach ($file_lines as $line)
    {
    list($b4_key, $key, $b4_value, $value) = explode('"', $line);
    if (preg_match("/Lang/", $b4_key))
        { $Lang[$key] = $value; }
    }
?>    
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Language Editor</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<h1><?= $array_file ?></h1>
<? if (!isset($is_post)) { ?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
<? } ?>
<table>
<?
// loop through the $Lang array and display the Lang value (if POSTed) or a form element
foreach ($Lang as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>";
    echo isset($is_post) ? "= \"$value\"": "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$value\">";
    echo "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    ?>
</table>
<? if (!isset($is_post)) { ?>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I can not read array and Keys from lang.php.

Script writer, writes:
all lines in array.txt did do set $ Bid [] will be lost.

But I want lang.php after the change save as a PHP file that would go?

I want to create a drop-down list and load array with matching keys, change key text and save.

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Once again - "I have found the script and it doesn't work"... What have you tried to make it work? What output do you get? What do you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read lang.php file.
You should include it.

Better way:

```
require_once('lang.php'); // or require_once($array_file);
```

and remove these lines:

```
// read the array into $Lang[]
$file_lines = file($array_file);
$Lang = array();
foreach ($file_lines as $line)
    {
    list($b4_key, $key, $b4_value, $value) = explode('"', $line);
    if (preg_match("/Lang/", $b4_key))
        { $Lang[$key] = $value; }
    }
```

## # # # # # # # #

As I understand your file contents only one language, doesn't it?
If no, will be a little modifications in the code.

```
<?
// edit the values of an array ($Lang["key"] = "value";) in the file below
$array_file = "lang.php";

// if POSTed, save file
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    unset($_POST['submit']); // remove the submit button from the name/value pairs
    $is_post = true; // set flag for use below

    // write over the original file, and write a backup copy with the date/time
    write_file($array_file, $new_array);
    write_file($array_file . date("_Y-m-d_h-ia"), $new_array);

    file_put_contents($array_file, serialize(array(
        'timestamp' => time(), // after you can display this value in your preffered format
        'data' => serialize($_POST)
    )));
}

$Lang_content = @unserialize(@file_get_contents($array_file));
if (!array_key_exists('data', $Lang_content)) {
    $Lang_content = array(
        'timestamp' => 0, // or time()
        'data' => serialize(array())
    );
}

$Lang_template = array( // If you want
    'TEXT'      => "baer",
    'GRET'      => "hallo",
    'FACE'      => "face",
    'HAPY'      => "happy",
    'TOOL'      => "tool",
);

$Lang = array_merge(
    $Lang_template,
    unserialize($Lang_content['data'])
);

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Language Editor</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<h1><?= $array_file ?></h1>
<? if (!isset($is_post)) { ?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <? } ?>
    <table>
        <?
        // loop through the $Lang array and display the Lang value (if POSTed) or a form element
        foreach ($Lang as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>";
            echo isset($is_post) ? "= \"$value\"" : "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$value\">";
            echo "</td></tr>\n";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <? if (!isset($is_post)) { ?>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But as for me the lang.php is not a good idea.
Just serialize language arrays and save to some file (not php).
After you can read and unserialize and will get the same array. I think that is the better way.

Comment: Hello Vitaly,
Thanks for your tip does it work.

But I want to save the lang.php as PHP, that would go? Now, after saving it deletes everything else. :-(

Comment: I just read that is very exciting and I would love to do that with the serialize, unserialize. Can you write some code for me and so help me on the jumps?

Comment: Read:
$Lang = unserialize(@file_get_contents('LANG_FILE'));

Write:
file_put_contents('LANG_FILE', serialize($Lang));

Comment: To improve this you can also use the template Lang array:
    
    $Lang_template = array(/* TEMPLATE VALUES */);
    $Lang = array_merge($Lang_template, unserialize(@file_get_contents('LANG_FILE')));
    
If the lang file is corrupted (or just not exists) or doesn't have some variable then the Template values will be used.

Comment: Vitaly,
the script will be an administration area extension. Users can select language files (lang.php), edit keys, add new array with keys and save.


Can you write me a script like this? :-)

Comment: result look like that:

a:2:{s:9:"timestamp";i:1373530031;s:4:"data";s:114:"a:5:{s:4:"TEXT";s:4:"baer";s:4:"GRET";s:3:"Te5";s:4:"FACE";s:4:"face";s:4:"HAPY";s:3:"ha5";s:4:"TOOL";s:4:"tool";}";}

Not right PHP File.

Comment: Line 11,12 : comment;

Line 21 : change to "if (!@array_key_exists('data', $Lang_content)) {"

Comment: Do the mistakes in lang.php file?

Comment: But if you want **PHP** lang file you shouldn't change anything except my answer's first part.

Comment: Sorry! Not does work, here my current code by Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/uKZrh8Bs

Comment: I've tested just now. It works.

One moment: if you don't need "lang template", change lines 36-39 with **"$Lang = unserialize($Lang_content['data']);"**

Comment: I cant see my input elements. :-) Only "Save" button.

current Code: http://pastebin.com/UDHc09ZX

Comment: Try to check variables: $is_post and $_POST (with **var_dump** I suggest). Do they have values?

Comment: but I can remove this if query, the same problem. I think problem is here:
foreach ($Lang as $key => $value) {

Comment: Yes, you're right. And $Lang got value from lang.php.
Check content of lang.php after read and unserialize. Are all the data there?

Comment: lang.php look like this:

<?php
$Lang = array(
'TEXT'      => "baer",
'GRET'      => "hallo",
'FACE'      => "face",
'HAPY'      => "happy",
'TOOL'      => "tool",
);

Comment: OK, lang.php has PHP data (not serialized). Then to "read" data from lang.php you should use **require_once**. To write - use this code:

$lang_php = '<?php', PHP_EOL, '$Lang = array(', PHP_EOL;
foreach ($_POST as $key => value) {
   $lang_php .= '$Lang["$key"] => "' . trim($value) . '",', PHP_EOL; }
$lang_php .= ');', PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('lang.php', $lang_php);

Comment: You are just great guy. :-)

Where can I find the donation button.?

Comment: I would like your valuable time not steal, but I have yet to implement 2 things then the extension for me would be perfect.

1) I just wanted to <select> <option> </ select> build around outside, unfortunately did not work.

2) Second, actual point would be to have the possibility to insert new array with key.

Comment: Give me a sample, please. I don't understand about "select". You want to dynamically append language file with a new entity, don't you?

Comment: Vitaly,
I would like to create a list of all the "ARRAY" (Dropdown.).

If you select the array to be loaded on the right side right KEY.

Would it go? See here: http://dev.oxid-design.com/test/edit.php